# Why does pylance point out a type issue when using ABCMeta.register?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, typechecking, pylance

Example code using `register` to add `C` as a virtual subclass of `A`:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> int:
        ...

class B(A):  # normal subclass
    def f(self) -> int:
        return 1

class C:  # no subclass, to be registered
    def f(self) -> int:
        return 2

A.register(C)

def caller(x: A):
    print(isinstance(x, A))
    print(x.f())

b = B()
c = C()

caller(b)
caller(c)  # ← This is where pylance will complain
```

This yields:

```
True
1
True
2
```

So this works as expected. However, Pylance complains about a type issue in the very last line of the code: `Argument of type "C" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "A" in function "caller" "C" is incompatible with "A"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues`.

Why is that?

Comment: Update: mypy complains too: `error: Argument 1 to "caller" has incompatible type "C"; expected "A"`

Comment: Related: [mypy issue #2922](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2922), [mypy issue #1459](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1459). As a workaround you can `assert isinstance(c, A)` before every call. But that's not a solution.